# vim recorded session like doitlive

Tags: autocompletion

I have a presentation to make for a conference and I'm not allowed to use slides, only live coding.

Is there a tool in vim which will help me avoid typos ? :)

Something like [doitlive](https://doitlive.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which you can click on any key on the keyboard and it will print the next right letter from the provided file.

> doitlive is a tool for live presentations in the terminal.
>
> It reads a file of shell commands and replays the commands in a fake terminal session as you type random characters.

Comment: I don't really see the point of fake typing in such a presentation. Either the topic is on how you develop or how you use vim and then it is interesting for your audience to see you actually coding. Or the main topic is to show your code or a sequence of commands and then it might be a better idea to have you script ready and execute each of its part individually (how to do that will mainly depend on what you are showing)

Comment: Using saved folds is less cool way to present, live coding without typos is better. I need to present 300~ lines C & ARM code.

Comment: That's a lot of line to autotype. I'm not aware of a plugin like the one you're looking for maybe you can abuse a snippet manager and create snippets for every section of code you want to show. Or maybe you can come up with a simple vimscript solution which will read files one by one in a directory, that would require a little bit of development.

Comment: I not only adding into the file I also replace code sections. can you point me to a half-way plugin ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know such a plugin, google would be more helpful than me on this one. But I think your best bet is either developing something yourself or waiting for [your github issue](https://github.com/sloria/doitlive/issues/83) to get an answer.